# How to better implement drop down menu in react js web

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I got put on a new react project and I am still new and learning how to use react, we don't have a senior engineer in the team is just me. I am trying to achieve something similar to what this website has https://www.konrad.com/ on the `capabilities`. That is a drop down menu kind of experience.

I have the code so far but I am not able to make services drop down show when clicked and disappear when we hover away.

Here is my `MenuDropdown.jsx` code.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const MenuDropdown = () =>  {

    return (
        <div className="absolute top-20 right-0 bg-white shadow-lg text-gray-500 w-full mx-auto p-12 hidden">
            <div className="flex flex-row flex-nowrap space-x-6 justify-between">
                <div className="space-y-2 flex-none w-3/12 border-r">
                    <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-slate-900">Services</h2>
                    <p className="text-base">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto..</p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
                    <h2 className="text-base text-slate-900 font-bold">Option 1</h2>
                    <p className="text-sm">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto..</p>
                    <Link to="strategy">
                        <button className="border border-slate-900 flex-none w-6/12 text-black py-2 px-4 rounded-full capitalize text-center hover:bg-slate-900 hover:text-white">
                            <span className="text-xs">Learn More</span>
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
                    <h2 className="text-base text-slate-900 font-bold">Option 2</h2>
                    <p className="text-sm">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto..</p>
                    <Link to="design">
                        <button className="border border-slate-900 flex-none w-6/12 text-black py-2 px-4 rounded-full capitalize text-center hover:bg-slate-900 hover:text-white">
                            <span className="text-xs">Learn More</span>
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
                    <h2 className="text-base text-slate-900 font-bold">Option 3</h2>
                    <p className="text-sm">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto.</p>
                    <Link to="technology">
                        <button className="border border-slate-900 flex-none w-6/12 text-black py-2 px-4 rounded-full capitalize text-center hover:bg-slate-900 hover:text-white">
                            <span className="text-xs">Learn More</span>
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MenuDropdown
```

Here is my `Navigation.jsx`

```
import logo from './favicon.png'
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer"
import MenuDropdown from "./MenuDropdown"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Navigation() {

   const [ref, inView] = useInView({ triggerOnce: false })

   const megaMenu = document.getElementById('mega-menu')

   return (
    <motion.nav className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap px-6 lg:px-12 py-8 max-w-full mx-auto" ref={ref} initial={{ y: -10, opacity: 0 }} animate={inView? { y: 0, opacity: 1 }: {}} exit={{ y: -10, opacity: 0 }} transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}>
        <a href="/" className="flex flex-row items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6 lg:pr-16 space-x-2">
          <img src={logo} className='w-8 h-8' alt='Logo'></img>
          <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl tracking-tight">Sample </h2>
        </a>
        
        <div id='menu' className="block lg:hidden">
          <button className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-slate-200 border-slate-400 duration-100 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
            <svg className="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="lg:flex flex-none w-6/12 hidden">
          <div className="lg:flex-grow flex flex-rows space-x-12 text-sm">
            <div className="flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white">
              <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
              <Link to="projects" className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4">
                Home
              </Link>
            </div>

            <div id="mega-menu" className="flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white">
              <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
              <div className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 mr-4 cursor-pointer">
                Services
              </div>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1} stroke="currentColor" className="w-4 h-4">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white">
              <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
              <a href="about" className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4">
                About
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white">
              <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
              <a href="careers" className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4">
                Careers
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white">
              <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
              <a href="contact" className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4">
                Contact
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        
        <MenuDropdown></MenuDropdown>
        
    </motion.nav>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically what you need to do is add some state of the navigation so it can keep track of whether or not the dropdown should be visible. Based on this state, we will set the menu to visible or not.

Start by adding a `useState` to the `Navigation.jsx`... let's say

```
export default function Navigation() {
   const [ref, inView] = useInView({ triggerOnce: false });
   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
...
```

Then add a click handler to the `service` menu item so it will change the state to the dropdown to `true`

```
 <div id="mega-menu" className="flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white"
    onClick={() => setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)}>
    <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
        <div className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 mr-4 cursor-pointer">
            Services
        </div>
...
```

Now we want to pass both the state and setState to the dropdown

```
<MenuDropdown isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />
```

In the `MenuDropdown.jsx` you want to adjust the function to take in those new props

```
const MenuDropdown = ({ isOpen, setIsOpen }) => {
```

Now that we have the state and setState passed, we want to adjust the className based on the state of isOpen. On the wrapper div...

```
<div
   className={`absolute top-20 right-0 bg-white shadow-lg text-gray-500 w-full mx-auto p-12 ${isOpen ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}>...
```

Then add the handler for when the mouse leaves the wrapper, by adding an `onMouseLeave` event

```
onMouseLeave={() => setIsOpen(false)}
```

Making the final code for the dropdown wrapper:

```
<div
   className={`absolute top-20 right-0 bg-white shadow-lg text-gray-500 w-full mx-auto p-12 ${isOpen ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}
   onMouseLeave={() => setIsOpen(false)}>...
```

Notes: This only works for one dropdown, if you are going to have multiple I would recommend creating an object for the nav items, and a flag for isDropdown that will dynamically update the Dropdown with the correct information and state. However this should get you started.